# Null pointer exception inside for Loop

Tags: apex, exception, loop, null-pointer

**Here is the code:**

```
for(Requests curRequest : requestList){
       if (curRequest.varSRProduct!= null ){
            for(SObject so : curRequest.varSRProduct){
             //code
            }
       }
}
```

Wrapper Class:
Wrapper class

```
global class Requests {
     @InvocableVariable global Boolean isActive;
     @InvocableVariable global Boolean srBoolean;
     @InvocableVariable global List<SObject> varSRProduct = new List<SObject>();
}
global class Results {
    @InvocableVariable global List<SObject> varSupportedProducts;
}
```

- requestList - Wrapper class
- varSRProduct - List of objects

Tried `isEmpty`, `list size()`. Nothing is working except `requestlist[0].varSRProduct!= null` which is not a good practice.

Comment: Can you please share your wrapper class as well.

Comment: Hi @Adarsh - can you please let us know how are you setting the `varSRProduct ` in your code.

Comment: we are having this error when varSRProduct is null which is coming from the Lightning Flow. But when I do null check I get this exception

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with you wrapper class object instantiation. If the `varSRProduct` is mandatory component of the wrapper then it has to be initialized properly with initialization of wrapper. To elaborate my point, please understand below points

e.g. Following example will always produce null

```
List<sobject> sobjectlist;
System.debug(sobjectlist);  // results in <null>
```

To correct the above issue, you could check if it is null or not

```
if(sobjectlist != null) { 
   // then add items to the list
   // perform another <if> check to perform an data integrity on the list items
}
```

**OR, you should initialize it correctly**

```
List<sobject> sobjectlist = new List<sobject>(); 
system.debug(sobjectlist);   // results in <()> - an empty list
OR
List<sobject> sobjectlist = [SELECT Id FROM sobject];
system.debug(sobjectlist);   // results in <{item1, itemsx.. }> - list of sobject
```

Now, I know the list itself can't be null, so I will just check for the items using either `isEmpty()` or `size()` methods. So, may be you need to recheck your wrapper class code and see how you are initializing the `varSRProduct` list.

Comment: List<sobject> sobjectlist = new List<sobject>(); - This is how I initialized. But still faced the same issue!

Also the if condition
if(requestList !=null){
if(curRequest.varSRProduct!= null )
}}

Wrapper class

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add your wrapper class in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in your code, the `curRequest.varSRProduct` is `null`. Therefore, if you will call on `null` the `isEmpty()` method, you will get `null pointer exception`.

Using `curRequest.varSRProduct != null && !curRequest.varSRProduct.isEmpty()` should solve your problem with exception.

Nevertheless, the `!curRequest.varSRProduct.isEmpty()` part is probably not needed as if the list is empty the iteration will be skipped.

Comment: curRequest.varSRProduct != null - I even tried that but same exception!:(

Comment: then the error is happening somewhere else in your code, pls update your question with rest of the code

Comment: This is the line where the error occurs.
If I replace the if condition with --> if(requestlist[0].varSRProduct!= null) there is no issue.